# Inserting result of function into a table

Tags: r

I have a function, which return the completeness of each column in a dataframe:

```
completness <- function(df){
  result <- apply(df, 2, function(x) (1 - length(x[is.na(x) == TRUE]) / length(x)))
  return (round(result, digits=4))
}

completeness1 <- completness(data)
print(completeness1)

write.table(completeness1)
```

Which result in

[image]

And

[image]

I thought 'write.table' actually made a nice table with borders and without "" around the column name. Is there a nice and easy way to actually append the values to a table?

**EDIT**

Best solution so far (proposed by Edo):

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should consider `write.table( data.frame(t(1-colMeans(is.na(df))))`

Comment: Hi Onyambu, I may misintrepretted your solution, I get the following error: ```Error: Incomplete expression: 
write.table(data.frame(t(1-colMeans(is.na(data))))```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
knitr::kable(completeness1)
#> |  x| id| url|
#> |--:|--:|---:|
#> |  1|  1|   1|
```

Comment: I still miss the borders, and would also like to overwrite "x" with a better headername. Upwote, due to a more beautiful solution than mine (see edit in post).

Comment: ops, sorry, I thought that `completeness1` was a dataframe. Try with `knitr::kable(t(completeness1))`

Comment: Still no borders, but we are getting closer.

Comment: Force: format = "markdown" inside the kable function